# A .bat file that searches for any exe file in a specific folder and

Tags: batch-file

I need help with the following code:

```
@echo off
for /r %%a in (*.exe) do echo %%a >> get_exefiles.txt
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set count=0
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *.exe') do @(
    set filename[!count!]=%%a
    set /a count = count + 1
)
set /a choose = (%random% * 32768 + %random%) %% count
set chosen=!filename[%choose%]!
echo %chosen%
pause

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *.exe /b') do call :ren_it "%%a"
goto :eof
:ren_it
set max=999 
set min=1
set /a rng=%random% %% (max - min + 1)+ min
echo ren "%~1" "%rng%_%var%.exe
```

so far I managed to make the first two points here work:

1. **Look/search for any EXE file in a specific folder.** (done! although not sure if this is the right approach?)
2. **Finds more than one EXE file and chooses one randomly.**
3. **Rename the exe file to some random name. (this part frustrates me I can't get it to work)**

And if possible, how can I approach any of these?

1. Add new random key under the name Hello_World_RandomNUM to the
   registry (give an arbitrary value to the key)
2. Create new sub folder
3. Create a file of a big size in the sub folder (eg. 12MB). The content of the file can be any random thing.
4. An infinite loop that just ping some machine and print the results of the null device.
5. Add new user account with specific username and password.

Hopefully, someone could help since these are some potential questions I might be getting in a lab test tomorrow (security student here o/)
thank you in advance!

Comment: For #3 Please explain the issues you are experiencing with descriptions of behavior or error messages.

Comment: although it's in the same batch file it doesn't run at all. it is the part of the code that starts with:                                   for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *.exe /b') do call :ren_it "%%a"

Comment: Do not vandalize your questions just because you've got your answer. That prevents future readers from learning the same things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to eliminate spaces in variable names before = signs.
Even though in `SET /A` it is not an issue, in most places it is an issue.

This seems to work here - I didn't rename the file but that should work too.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set count=0
for /r %%a in (*.exe) do (
    set filename[!count!]=%%a
    set /a count=count + 1
)
set /a choose=(%random% * 32768 + %random%) %%count
set chosen=!filename[%choose%]!
echo "%chosen%" "%choose%"
pause
ren "%chosen%" "%choose%.exe"
```

To get a random exe name:

Here you can `skip` a number of filenames to get a random exe name, and rename it, branching to :done to exit the loop. `skip=` starts at 1 so you can blank the variable to get the 1st filename from the loop, as the first line does.

```
if %number% GTR 0 (set skip=skip=%number%) else (set skip=)
for /f "%skip% delims=" %%a in ('dir *.exe /b') do (
   ren "%%a" "random name.exe"
   goto :done
)
:done
```